# Convert Function Output into Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am using `nsepython` library for data extraction. I was extracting lot size for particular symbol from function `nse_get_fno_lot_sizes` of `nsepython` library.

I want the output of function `nse_get_fno_lot_sizes` in dataframe format instead of current format.

Complete Code - https://github.com/aeron7/nsepython/blob/master/nsepython/rahu.py

`nse_get_fno_lot_sizes` function-

```
def nse_get_fno_lot_sizes(symbol="all",mode="list"):
    url="https://archives.nseindia.com/content/fo/fo_mktlots.csv"

    if(mode=="list"):
        s=requests.get(url).text
        res_dict = {}
        for line in s.split('\n'):
          if line != '' and re.search(',', line) and (line.casefold().find('symbol') == -1):
              (code, name) = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')[1:3]]
              res_dict[code] = int(name)
        if(symbol=="all"):
            return res_dict
        if(symbol!=""):
            return res_dict[symbol.upper()]

    if(mode=="pandas"):
        payload = pd.read_csv(url)
        if(symbol=="all"):
            return payload
        else:
            payload = payload[(payload.iloc[:, 1] == symbol.upper())]
            return payload
```

My Code-

```
print(nse_get_fno_lot_sizes("adaniports","pandas"))
print(type(nse_get_fno_lot_sizes))
```

Output-

```
                UNDERLYING            SYMBOL    JUL-22  AUG-22  SEP-22  DEC-22  MAR-23  JUN-23  DEC-23  JUN-24  DEC-24  JUN-25  DEC-25  JUN-26  DEC-26  JUN-27
8            ADANI PORT & SEZ LTD   ADANIPORTS  1250    1250    1250
<class 'function'>
```

I want to convert the output getting from the `nse_get_fno_lot_sizes` function as dataframe.

Documentation- https://aeron7.github.io/nsepython/documentation/nsetools.html#top-losers-gainers

Comment: ```df = nse_get_fno_lot_sizes("adaniports","pandas")``` returns adataframe. Check by doing ```df.info()```. Have I missunderstood the question?

Comment: It Worked !!! I missed using variable `df` while calling the function.